# Android 10: How to get MAC address from Socket / Client PC without /proc/net/arp

Tags: android, macos, sockets, connection

Since 2 days I'm searching for a solution of my problem with the MAC address of the connected server.
In my app "Remote for iTunes DJ & UpNext" I need the MAC address of the iTunes PC for the WOL function.

Unfortunately the function `FileReader("/proc/net/arp")` doesn't work anymore with Android 10.

I tried a lot of things like:

```
InetAddress address = socket.getInetAddress();
NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
```

...but I get only NULL as result...

In Google Play I found apps like "Network Analyzer" with this App I saw the MAC address of the iTunes Server PC.

It looks that there is a way to get the MAC address of a device in the network.

Any Idea how I can get the MAC addresses?

Thanks
Erdal

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with following code:

```
private static final String IP_CMD = "ip neighbor";
...
BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    Process ipProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(IP_CMD);
    ipProc.waitFor();
    if (ipProc.exitValue() != 0) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to access ARP entries");
    }

    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ipProc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] neighborLine = line.split("\\s+");

        // We don't have a validated ARP entry for this case.
        if (neighborLine.length <= 4) {
            continue;
        }

        String ipaddr = neighborLine[0];
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ipaddr);
        if (addr.isLinkLocalAddress() || addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
            continue;
        }

        String macAddress = neighborLine[4];
        ....
```